# Как обработать нажатие inline кнопки в Telegram боте

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Пишу бота на C#, используя Telegram Bot API. Как я могу обработать нажатие inline кнопки, чтобы пользователю отправилось сообщение? Мой вариант не работает:

```
    private async Task HandleUpdateAsync(ITelegramBotClient client, Update update, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(update));

        switch (update.Type)
        {
            case Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.UpdateType.Message:
                Message message = update.Message;
                switch (update.Message.Text.ToLower())
                {
                    case "/start":
                        await client.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat, "Добро пожаловать на борт!",
                                                          replyMarkup: GetStartMenuButtons(),
                                                          cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                        return;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.UpdateType.CallbackQuery:
                CallbackQuery query = update.CallbackQuery;

                if (query.Data == "ask_question")
                {
                    await client.SendTextMessageAsync(update.Message.Chat, "Напишите свой вопрос",
                                                      cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Здесь, когда я обращаюсь к объекту update, чтобы выцепить ChatId, мне выкидывается исключение, что ChatId null.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что вы не оттуда хватаете chatId. Его следует брать из CallbackQuery, в коде ниже правильный пример (у моего бота работает нормально)

```
long chatId = update.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id;
```